# How to apply 'Markdown style for reply with InlineKeyboardButton?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, telegram-bot, telegraf

How to apply `{ parse_mode: 'Markdown' }` for reply with **InlineKeyboardButton** ?

```
const Telegraf = require("telegraf");
const Extra = require("telegraf/extra");
const Markup = require("telegraf/markup");

const keyboard = Markup.inlineKeyboard([
  Markup.urlButton("❤️", "http://telegraf.js.org"),
  Markup.callbackButton("Delete", "delete")
]);

const myReply = "Hello *mate*, __where are you ?__"

bot.on("message", ctx =>
  ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, myReply, Extra.markup(keyboard))
);
```

Is there any option to add markdown style for message with InlineKeyboardButton ?

Comment: Mo. could you please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

## Telegraf 4

According to [Telegraf 4.0 changelog](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/releases/tag/v4.0.0), **`Extra` is removed entirely**.

If you have an inline-keyboard in a ***simple*** `ctx.reply()` (see [the example](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/e34c4d74a1792e13fac38ea1e7baa1c536cf0a7f/docs/examples/keyboard-bot.js#L72-L79)), just use `.replyWithHTML()` or `.replyWithMarkdown()` or `.replyWithMarkdownV2()` instead of `.reply()`.

```js
ctx.replyWithMarkdownV2(
        '*formatted* text',
        Markup.inlineKeyboard([
            Markup.button.callback('Coke', 'Coke'),
            Markup.button.callback('Dr Pepper', 'Dr Pepper'),
            Markup.button.callback('Pepsi', 'Pepsi')
        ])
)
```

If you have a ***more complex*** situation, you can pass an object like below as the appropriate argument to the `ctx.reply()` or `ctx.telegram.sendMessage()` or `bot.telegram.editMessageText()` etc.:

```js
const extraObject = {
    parse_mode: 'HTML',
    ...Markup.inlineKeyboard([
        Markup.button.callback('Coke', 'Coke'),
        Markup.button.callback('Pepsi', 'Pepsi'),
    ]),
}

ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, 'My <b>formatted</b> reply', extraObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

To add Markdown styling to your message, chain `markdown()` to `Extra.markup()`, like this:

```js
const keyboard = Markup.inlineKeyboard([
  Markup.urlButton("❤️", "http://telegraf.js.org"),
  Markup.callbackButton("Delete", "delete")
]);

const myReply = "Hello *mate*, _where are you ?_"

bot.on("message", ctx => {
    ctx.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, myReply, Extra.markdown().markup(keyboard));
});
```

[image: example markup style]